# Session error in magento

Tags: error, magento-1.9, session

Getting this error -

> Fatal error: session_start() [function.session-start]: Failed to
>   initialize storage module: user (path: /tmp) in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 125

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may be running a different version of PHP than Magento requires. Try changing your PHP version and see if it is working correctly.

Reference : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/magento/php-error-on-new-magento-installation